# Alternate row colors in RDLC using flat dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I am using a tablix in an rdlc report which uses a flat (Single row datasource), however the values which are displayed are in multiple rows. 
I need to add alternate row coloring for the same,I cannot use a RowNumber as I am working off a flat dataset.
Are there any other approaches I can take ? 
TIA

Comment: How you are converting single row to multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you are referring to as a flat single row datasource appearing as multiple rows.  I am assuming what you actually have is a regular table of values.

You can use a combination of `CountDistinct` and `RunningValue` to calculate a row number in the background that you can then use to set the BackgroundColor property of your rows.

For example the following expression in the BackgroundColor property of the tablix row

```
=iif((RunningValue(CountDistinct(Fields!Serial.Value), Sum, "DataSet1") mod 2) = 0, "Tomato", "LimeGreen")
```

Sets this table to have alternating red and green rows, without editing the datasource at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the Background color for the row to the following expression, changing the data set name and color choices.

```
=IIF(RowNumber("AdverseEventsDataSet") mod 2 = 0,"Silver","LightGrey")
```